# Mysql leftjoin issue with NULL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have been using left join and have found it to be quite useful. Today I have come across a problem where the right side NULL is not showing. First table is **category** which is as below:

```
id    name
1     ROR
2    Mutation
3    Partition
```

Second table is **scheme_category** which is as below:

```
id    scheme_id    category_id    period
1       12             1           3/2016
2       12             2           3/2016
3       12             1           4/2016
4       12             2           4/2016
5       12             3           4/2016
6       12             1           5/2016
7       12             3           5/2016
```

For period 3/2016, no value exists for category_id 3. Similarly, for period 5/2016, no value exists for category_id 2. I have written a query using category and scheme_category table so that non-existent categories in **scheme_category** table are shown as NULL:

```
select category.name, period 
from category 
    left join scheme_category on category.id= scheme_category.category_id
```

But this query is not showing any fields as NULL. Please guide in this regard.

Comment: That is  correct because in your scheme_category table it contain all distinct category values try to insert new value to category then you will get null record

Comment: This query obviously did not show any fields as `NULL` for your sample data.

Comment: Please try this query for your solution:

`select category.name, period, category_id 
from category 
    left join scheme_category on category.id= scheme_category.category_id `

Comment: I have put the question here after trying it for quite sometime. Which part of it did not show any research effort or make it unclear ? Maybe down voting this question has shown how knowledgeable you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you join on category id only and the category ids match. You need to have a complete list of category id - period pairs and join the scheme_category table on this list.

Either you create a separate period table in which you list the periods or you get the list of periods from scheme_category table itself. Then create a cartesian join between the list of periods and category ids and left join this dataset on the scheme_category table.

Since the 2nd option is the more complicated, I'll provide a sample code for that:

```
select
from
    (select distinct period from scheme_category) t1
join
    category  --note that there is no join condition -> creating a Cartesian join
left join
    scheme_category on t1.period=scheme_category.period and category.id=scheme_category.category_id
```

Comment: Thanks shadow for your help. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I created in PhpMyAdmin two tables similar to yours.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT category.name, scheme_category.peroid
FROM `scheme_category`
LEFT JOIN category
ON category.id = scheme_category.category_id
```

...and it gives me:

```
name | peroid
ROR  | 3/2016
Mutation | 3/2016
ROR  |4/2016
```

So works good.

Comment: The question was why the OP is not seeing the `null`s they expect, not whether the query works.